# Allow null for Integer field in Java Custom Annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I am creating a custom annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyFramework {

    public Integer index() default null; // Compiler complains here

}
```

The compiler  complains that `null` is not allowed. I do not want to make the index field primitive type `int` as it would not make sense. Is there a way to have a default `null` value for annotation fields?

Comment: Sorry bit a tired with my last answer, this dupe is hopefully what you need.

Comment: The answers in the linked page does not address this question as it is about a `Integer` class.